# Run configuration IntelliJ for 2D game

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration

I was importing the source code of a Java game to my local IntelliJ (community edition 2.3.2019) and try to make it run. I'm new to Java btw. 
I got the code from here: https://github.com/janbodnar/Java-Space-Invaders

What I did is download the code from the repo, export the zip file in a folder and import it as a project in IntelliJ. After importing a lot of my project files appear red as you can see here:
[IntelliJ red icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC06h.png)

My first question is: Why are these icons red? And how can I find out why IntelliJ is marking them red? I tried by hovering over these icons, but nothing happens / indicates what's wrong.

Also: Afaik in order to make this project run I need to take care of the run configuration. I tried this, but the main class is not choosable if I choose the path com.zetcode.SpaceInvaders.java (where the main class is part of the code).

What am I doing wrong? How can I run this project/code in IntelliJ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow these steps:
1. IntelliJ -> New Project-> Project from existing resources(the unzipped code directory).
2. Follow the next steps as given by project explorer.
3. Remember this project uses jdk above 10 as it uses "var" keyword.
4. So, go to the project settings if the jdk in step 2 was selected below 10.
I couldn't see any red marked files. I just ran the SpaceInvaders.java file to run the project & the game started.

Comment: Your suggestion worked, many thanks. The run config automatically detected SpaveInvaders.java as the main cIass. I still don't get what the difference is between importing a project and creating a new project from an existing source ;-)